# Unknown webserver listening on port 80

Tags: windows-7, windows, webserver, iis

I was trying to install Apache, and I noticed it was forced to port 8080 because IIS was already using port 80. So I disabled the IIS service, and now there's some *other* server that's still using the same port. It contains no files, I can't see any related services, and the only hint I have is this `Server` respose header:

```
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

How can I get rid of this other server, or at least get it to move? I've never seen it on any other computers with the same setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have Web Deployment Tool running.

Go to **Control Panel > Security > Administrative Tools** and disable it, or

```
net stop msdepsvc
```

Answer (score 2):

cports is a very useful tool on Windows. It will list all programs and the port numbers used by the programs.

http://www.nirsoft.net