# How do I reconfigure Apache to use another port?

Tags: windows-10, webserver

After uninstalling IP camera I opened Mamp wich use port 80 and the following message appeared:

`APACHE' needs open port '80' which is already being used by another service or application. Please reconfigure 'APACHE'to use free port`

Please how can I fix it?

Comment: Relevant: [Unknown webserver listening on port 80](http://superuser.com/q/399557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port used by Apache is set in the configuration files using this syntax :

```
Listen 80
```

By Default, it is located in the httpd.conf or the website config file.

Comment: Listen is nor recognise in my windows 10 dos prompt.

Comment: I found IIS items cheked in windows functionnality after reading others issues